# Get Value of dynamically create dropdownlist in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and servlet for 1 month, and there are many things that I am still unsure off.. Inside a JSP, I have a dropdownlist(the values inside are grab from database) and it would be dynamically created on the number that the user keyed in. Example, the user key in 3, this digit would store in session, and 3 dropdownlist would be generated.

I am able to do this, however I am unable to grab the value of all the 3 dropdownlist in a servlet. and instead of getting 3 diff values, the output repeat the value of the first dropdownlist. Example "john,john,john" instead of "john, ken, andy".

JSP code:

```
    <form action="Adding" method="post"> 
    <% 
    session = request.getSession();
    ProjectGroup projGrp1  = (ProjectGroup)session.getAttribute("PROJECTNAME");

    //getMaxMember is the int that user keyed in
    int staff =projGrp1.getMaxMember();

    for(int i = 0; i < staff; i++) {
     %>

     <select name="list1"  >

     <%@page import="sit.bean.*,sit.data.*"%>

    <%
    GroupTaskManager mgr3 = new GroupTaskManager();

    GroupTask[] at3 = mgr3.getCheckBox();
    for(int g = 0; g < at3.length; g++) {
    %>

  <option><%=at3[g].getStaffName()%></option>

 <%
  }
  %>
  </select>

  <%
  }
  %>
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

In servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ProjectGroup projGrp = (ProjectGroup)session.getAttribute("PROJECTNAME");

            int member =  projGrp.getMaxMember();

    String total = null;
    for(int i=0; i< member; i++)
    {
        String names = request.getParameter("list1");
        total += names + " , ";
    }

    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

    pw.write("<HTML><BODY>");
            pw.write(total);
            pw.write("</HTML></BODY>");

    pw.close();


}
```

Can i set the downdownlist name like "list<%i%>", to set different id to each downdownlist? therefore i can retrieve each of them seperately???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `servlet` you are getting same parameter every time which is `list1` in loop.
and also in `JSP` creating `dropdownlist` with same `name` attribute,

that's why you are getting `john,john,john` instead of `john, ken, andy`.

Yes you can use `list<%i%>` to set different id as well as name

change your `select` with below in `JSP`

```
<select name="list<%=i%>"  >
```

and `for loop` in `servlet` with below

```
for(int i=0; i< member; i++)
{
    String names = request.getParameter("list1"+i);
    total += names + " , ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I addded <select name="list<%i%>"> in the jsp. But this error occur (curly line under the "i": 
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
- Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete